# How do I retrieve data from the OMDB API such as the poster, actors and etc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

The link of my code is : https://github.com/justgoof9/IMDB/blob/master/src/App.js

I can fetch the API but how can i use the data I fetched?

Comment: What do you mean by pass data? pass params to the request? or use the data you request?

Comment: Oh, I meant use the data that I requested.

Comment: you seen to already do that, you set a new state with the return, then use the return on render, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not a good idea to call componentWillMount from the code. This should only be called by React. Instead move all of that code to a new function and call it both from componentWillMount and from onSubmit.
2. You should not declare a constant (updatedMovies) and then modify it.
3. The first argument in setState is prevState which contains all the states, not just movies. You can do something like this:

   ```
   .then(data => {
       this.setState(({movies}) =>({ movies: movies.concat(data) }));
   });
   ```